# Dspace XMLUI config

Tags: java, tomcat, dspace

I installed and properly configured the dspace (I think), when I use the JSPUI interface works perfectly all actions. But when I try to use the interface XMLUI Tomcat returns me the following exception.

I honestly do not know WHAT is happening. If you can help me. Thank you very much!

My server logs:

https://mega.nz/#F!M4VFBRrC!CFA_gT0YREm589CFELGHmw

Java stacktrace:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 5
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.filter(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2756)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1253)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1142)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Kit.classOrNull(Kit.java:88)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaPackage.getPkgProperty(NativeJavaPackage.java:154)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaPackage.get(NativeJavaPackage.java:105)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptableObject.getProperty(ScriptableObject.java:1544)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getObjectProp(ScriptRuntime.java:1375)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getObjectProp(ScriptRuntime.java:1364)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:2965)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:2394)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:162)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:393)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2834)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:173)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.flow.javascript.fom.FOM_JavaScriptInterpreter.setupContext(FOM_JavaScriptInterpreter.java:465)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.flow.javascript.fom.FOM_JavaScriptInterpreter.callFunction(FOM_JavaScriptInterpreter.java:585)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.CallFunctionNode.invoke(CallFunctionNode.java:109)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.AbstractParentProcessingNode.invokeNodes(AbstractParentProcessingNode.java:55)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.MatchNode.invoke(MatchNode.java:87)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.AbstractParentProcessingNode.invokeNodes(AbstractParentProcessingNode.java:78)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.PipelineNode.invoke(PipelineNode.java:143)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.AbstractParentProcessingNode.invokeNodes(AbstractParentProcessingNode.java:78)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.PipelinesNode.invoke(PipelinesNode.java:81)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.ConcreteTreeProcessor.process(ConcreteTreeProcessor.java:239)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.ConcreteTreeProcessor.buildPipeline(ConcreteTreeProcessor.java:186)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.TreeProcessor.buildPipeline(TreeProcessor.java:260)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.MountNode.invoke(MountNode.java:107)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.AbstractParentProcessingNode.invokeNodes(AbstractParentProcessingNode.java:78)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.SelectNode.invoke(SelectNode.java:87)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.AbstractParentProcessingNode.invokeNodes(AbstractParentProcessingNode.java:55)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.MatchNode.invoke(MatchNode.java:87)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.AbstractParentProcessingNode.invokeNodes(AbstractParentProcessingNode.java:78)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.PipelineNode.invoke(PipelineNode.java:143)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.AbstractParentProcessingNode.invokeNodes(AbstractParentProcessingNode.java:78)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.PipelinesNode.invoke(PipelinesNode.java:81)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.ConcreteTreeProcessor.process(ConcreteTreeProcessor.java:239)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.ConcreteTreeProcessor.buildPipeline(ConcreteTreeProcessor.java:186)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.TreeProcessor.buildPipeline(TreeProcessor.java:260)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.MountNode.invoke(MountNode.java:107)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.AbstractParentProcessingNode.invokeNodes(AbstractParentProcessingNode.java:55)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.MatchNode.invoke(MatchNode.java:87)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.AbstractParentProcessingNode.invokeNodes(AbstractParentProcessingNode.java:78)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.PipelineNode.invoke(PipelineNode.java:143)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.AbstractParentProcessingNode.invokeNodes(AbstractParentProcessingNode.java:78)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.PipelinesNode.invoke(PipelinesNode.java:81)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.ConcreteTreeProcessor.process(ConcreteTreeProcessor.java:239)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.ConcreteTreeProcessor.buildPipeline(ConcreteTreeProcessor.java:186)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.TreeProcessor.buildPipeline(TreeProcessor.java:260)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.impl.SitemapSource.init(SitemapSource.java:277)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.impl.SitemapSource.<init>(SitemapSource.java:148)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.impl.SitemapSourceFactory.getSource(SitemapSourceFactory.java:62)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.CocoonSourceResolver.resolveURI(CocoonSourceResolver.java:153)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.CocoonSourceResolver.resolveURI(CocoonSourceResolver.java:183)
    at org.apache.cocoon.generation.FileGenerator.setup(FileGenerator.java:99)
    at org.dspace.app.xmlui.cocoon.AspectGenerator.setup(AspectGenerator.java:81)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor85.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cocoon.core.container.spring.avalon.PoolableProxyHandler.invoke(PoolableProxyHandler.java:71)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy96.setup(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.AbstractProcessingPipeline.setupPipeline(AbstractProcessingPipeline.java:343)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.impl.AbstractCachingProcessingPipeline.setupPipeline(AbstractCachingProcessingPipeline.java:710)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.AbstractProcessingPipeline.preparePipeline(AbstractProcessingPipeline.java:466)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.AbstractProcessingPipeline.prepareInternal(AbstractProcessingPipeline.java:480)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor129.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cocoon.core.container.spring.avalon.PoolableProxyHandler.invoke(PoolableProxyHandler.java:71)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy95.prepareInternal(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.impl.SitemapSource.init(SitemapSource.java:292)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.impl.SitemapSource.<init>(SitemapSource.java:148)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.impl.SitemapSourceFactory.getSource(SitemapSourceFactory.java:62)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.CocoonSourceResolver.resolveURI(CocoonSourceResolver.java:153)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.CocoonSourceResolver.resolveURI(CocoonSourceResolver.java:183)
    at org.apache.cocoon.generation.FileGenerator.setup(FileGenerator.java:99)
    at org.dspace.app.xmlui.cocoon.AspectGenerator.setup(AspectGenerator.java:81)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor85.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cocoon.core.container.spring.avalon.PoolableProxyHandler.invoke(PoolableProxyHandler.java:71)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy96.setup(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.AbstractProcessingPipeline.setupPipeline(AbstractProcessingPipeline.java:343)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.impl.AbstractCachingProcessingPipeline.setupPipeline(AbstractCachingProcessingPipeline.java:710)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.AbstractProcessingPipeline.preparePipeline(AbstractProcessingPipeline.java:466)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.AbstractProcessingPipeline.prepareInternal(AbstractProcessingPipeline.java:480)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor129.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cocoon.core.container.spring.avalon.PoolableProxyHandler.invoke(PoolableProxyHandler.java:71)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy95.prepareInternal(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.impl.SitemapSource.init(SitemapSource.java:292)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.impl.SitemapSource.<init>(SitemapSource.java:148)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.impl.SitemapSourceFactory.getSource(SitemapSourceFactory.java:62)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.CocoonSourceResolver.resolveURI(CocoonSourceResolver.java:153)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.CocoonSourceResolver.resolveURI(CocoonSourceResolver.java:183)
    at org.apache.cocoon.generation.FileGenerator.setup(FileGenerator.java:99)
    at org.dspace.app.xmlui.cocoon.AspectGenerator.setup(AspectGenerator.java:81)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor85.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cocoon.core.container.spring.avalon.PoolableProxyHandler.invoke(PoolableProxyHandler.java:71)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy96.setup(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.AbstractProcessingPipeline.setupPipeline(AbstractProcessingPipeline.java:343)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.impl.AbstractCachingProcessingPipeline.setupPipeline(AbstractCachingProcessingPipeline.java:710)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.AbstractProcessingPipeline.preparePipeline(AbstractProcessingPipeline.java:466)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.AbstractProcessingPipeline.prepareInternal(AbstractProcessingPipeline.java:480)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor129.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cocoon.core.container.spring.avalon.PoolableProxyHandler.invoke(PoolableProxyHandler.java:71)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy95.prepareInternal(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.impl.SitemapSource.init(SitemapSource.java:292)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.impl.SitemapSource.<init>(SitemapSource.java:148)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.impl.SitemapSourceFactory.getSource(SitemapSourceFactory.java:62)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.CocoonSourceResolver.resolveURI(CocoonSourceResolver.java:153)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.CocoonSourceResolver.resolveURI(CocoonSourceResolver.java:183)
    at org.apache.cocoon.generation.FileGenerator.setup(FileGenerator.java:99)
    at org.dspace.app.xmlui.cocoon.AspectGenerator.setup(AspectGenerator.java:81)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor85.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cocoon.core.container.spring.avalon.PoolableProxyHandler.invoke(PoolableProxyHandler.java:71)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy96.setup(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.AbstractProcessingPipeline.setupPipeline(AbstractProcessingPipeline.java:343)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.impl.AbstractCachingProcessingPipeline.setupPipeline(AbstractCachingProcessingPipeline.java:710)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.AbstractProcessingPipeline.preparePipeline(AbstractProcessingPipeline.java:466)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.AbstractProcessingPipeline.prepareInternal(AbstractProcessingPipeline.java:480)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor129.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cocoon.core.container.spring.avalon.PoolableProxyHandler.invoke(PoolableProxyHandler.java:71)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy95.prepareInternal(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.impl.SitemapSource.init(SitemapSource.java:292)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.impl.SitemapSource.<init>(SitemapSource.java:148)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.impl.SitemapSourceFactory.getSource(SitemapSourceFactory.java:62)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.CocoonSourceResolver.resolveURI(CocoonSourceResolver.java:153)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.CocoonSourceResolver.resolveURI(CocoonSourceResolver.java:183)
    at org.apache.cocoon.generation.FileGenerator.setup(FileGenerator.java:99)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor85.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cocoon.core.container.spring.avalon.PoolableProxyHandler.invoke(PoolableProxyHandler.java:71)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy96.setup(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.AbstractProcessingPipeline.setupPipeline(AbstractProcessingPipeline.java:343)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.impl.AbstractCachingProcessingPipeline.setupPipeline(AbstractCachingProcessingPipeline.java:710)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.AbstractProcessingPipeline.preparePipeline(AbstractProcessingPipeline.java:466)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.AbstractProcessingPipeline.process(AbstractProcessingPipeline.java:411)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor144.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cocoon.core.container.spring.avalon.PoolableProxyHandler.invoke(PoolableProxyHandler.java:71)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy95.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.SerializeNode.invoke(SerializeNode.java:147)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.AbstractParentProcessingNode.invokeNodes(AbstractParentProcessingNode.java:55)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.MatchNode.invoke(MatchNode.java:87)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.AbstractParentProcessingNode.invokeNodes(AbstractParentProcessingNode.java:78)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.PipelineNode.invoke(PipelineNode.java:143)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.AbstractParentProcessingNode.invokeNodes(AbstractParentProcessingNode.java:78)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.PipelinesNode.invoke(PipelinesNode.java:81)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.ConcreteTreeProcessor.process(ConcreteTreeProcessor.java:239)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.ConcreteTreeProcessor.process(ConcreteTreeProcessor.java:171)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.TreeProcessor.process(TreeProcessor.java:247)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.MountNode.invoke(MountNode.java:117)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.AbstractParentProcessingNode.invokeNodes(AbstractParentProcessingNode.java:55)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.MatchNode.invoke(MatchNode.java:87)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.AbstractParentProcessingNode.invokeNodes(AbstractParentProcessingNode.java:78)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.PipelineNode.invoke(PipelineNode.java:143)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.AbstractParentProcessingNode.invokeNodes(AbstractParentProcessingNode.java:78)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.PipelinesNode.invoke(PipelinesNode.java:81)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.ConcreteTreeProcessor.process(ConcreteTreeProcessor.java:239)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.ConcreteTreeProcessor.process(ConcreteTreeProcessor.java:171)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.TreeProcessor.process(TreeProcessor.java:247)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.MountNode.invoke(MountNode.java:117)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.AbstractParentProcessingNode.invokeNodes(AbstractParentProcessingNode.java:78)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.PipelineNode.invoke(PipelineNode.java:143)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.AbstractParentProcessingNode.invokeNodes(AbstractParentProcessingNode.java:78)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.PipelinesNode.invoke(PipelinesNode.java:81)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.ConcreteTreeProcessor.process(ConcreteTreeProcessor.java:239)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.ConcreteTreeProcessor.process(ConcreteTreeProcessor.java:171)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.TreeProcessor.process(TreeProcessor.java:247)
    at org.apache.cocoon.servlet.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:351)
    at org.apache.cocoon.servlet.RequestProcessor.service(RequestProcessor.java:169)
    at org.apache.cocoon.sitemap.SitemapServlet.service(SitemapServlet.java:84)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.cocoon.servletservice.ServletServiceContext$PathDispatcher.forward(ServletServiceContext.java:468)
    at org.apache.cocoon.servletservice.ServletServiceContext$PathDispatcher.forward(ServletServiceContext.java:443)
    at org.apache.cocoon.servletservice.spring.ServletFactoryBean$ServiceInterceptor.invoke(ServletFactoryBean.java:264)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy92.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.dspace.springmvc.CocoonView.render(CocoonView.java:113)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.dspace.app.xmlui.cocoon.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.dspace.app.xmlui.cocoon.DSpaceCocoonServletFilter.doFilter(DSpaceCocoonServletFilter.java:274)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.dspace.app.xmlui.cocoon.servlet.multipart.DSpaceMultipartFilter.doFilter(DSpaceMultipartFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.dspace.utils.servlet.DSpaceWebappServletFilter.doFilter(DSpaceWebappServletFilter.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2489)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I already tried to install earlier versions however unsuccessfully.

I tried to use versions of java 7/8.

Tomcat 7/8

Comment: Where does this stack trace appear when does it appear exactly? What's the DSpace version? Does it have any customizations?

Comment: Dspace 5.4 stable/

Tomcat 8

Java 1_8_74

Windows 10

I do not know what was missing set, but I followed strictly manual. If possible someone can tell me what I have set wrong or what was missing to be configured.

Comment: Java 8 and dspace are not friends. (And it's probably better to use Tomcat 7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem unistalled all version java 8 and installed only the version 7, and installed tomcat 7.0.30. Thank You Guys.

Answer (score 2):

See the [DS-3142 ticket](https://jira.duraspace.org/browse/DS-3142) which mentions either downgrading Tomcat to 7.0.x or upgrading Tomcat to 8.0.35

The core issue seems to be this bug in Tomcat 8.0.32: http://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58999

Answer (score 1):

Our team ran into a similar `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 3` when using DSpace's versioning functionality: `Sitemap: error calling function 'startCreateNewVersionItem'` in `Versioning/sitemap.xmap -> versioning.js`.

This exception happened in an environment with `apache-tomcat-8.0.32 64-bit` and `jdk1.8.0_73 64-bit` — whereas it did not occur in an environment with `apache-tomcat-8.0.26 64-bit` and `jdk1.8.0_60 64-bit`.

We could get the problematic system work with versioning by *downgrading* Apache Tomcat from version `8.0.32` to `8.0.26`, while still staying on the same Java 8 version.

Brendow, as your initial question was asked at a time when Tomcat `8.0.32` was Tomcat's latest version, you may have run into this particular problem.